# Why does a bit of my background gradient show at certain screen sizes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I can't figure out why I'm getting this little bit of green when the window is an odd number of pixels wide. I think it has something to do with sub-pixel rendering, but I'm just not sure where the green is coming from. It's just the 2nd div too which is weird.

I have some script that is animating the BG of this div. I'm sure this is part of the issue, but I can't figure out why it's only happening to my 2nd div.

I tried to manually set the width of this div, but I was hoping it would be responsive and scale with the window size.

```js
let currentStage = 1

function performAction(selectedStage) {
  currentStage = selectedStage
  let stages = document.body.getElementsByClassName('stage-flow-item')
  let stageLines = document.body.getElementsByClassName('stage-flow-line')
  console.log("selectedStage: " + selectedStage)
  for (let stage of stages) {
    if (stage.id > currentStage) {
      stage.classList.remove('completed')
      stage.classList.add('active')
    } else {
      stage.classList.remove('active')
      stage.classList.add('completed')
    }
  }

  for (let stageLine of stageLines) {
    if (stageLine.id > currentStage) {
      stageLine.classList.remove('lineCompleted')
      stageLine.classList.add('lineActive')
    } else {
      stageLine.classList.remove('lineActive')
      stageLine.classList.add('lineCompleted')
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.stage-flow-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.stage-flow-item {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  min-width: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.stage-flow-item.active {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.stage-flow-item.completed {
  background-color: #6ab04c;
}

.stage-flow-line {
  width: calc(100vw);
  height: 6px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  /* default color */
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #ddd 50%, #6ab04c 50%) right;
  position: relative;
  background-size: 200%;
  transition: .5s ease-out;
}

.stage-flow-line.lineCompleted {
  background-position: left;
  background-color: #6ab04c;
}

.stage-flow-line.lineActive {
  background-position: right;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="stage-flow-container">
  <div id=1 class="stage-flow-item" onclick="performAction(1)">1</div>
  <div id=1 class="stage-flow-line"></div>
  <div id=2 class="stage-flow-item" onclick="performAction(2)">2</div>
  <div id=2 class="stage-flow-line"></div>
  <div id=3 class="stage-flow-item" onclick="performAction(3)">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you setting background size to 200%? Seems like you'd want to just work with straight percent in your gradients.

Comment: @GeorgePrethesh Isherwood did not answer - he asked a question in the comments, which is what the comments are for. In no way was he harsh. That is a legit question and request to make the question more valuable to future visitors. OP, sub-pixel rendering can be a problem. What browser are you seeing this in (FF Dev edition 110.0b6 (64-bit) doesn't have the issue)?

Comment: Hey all! Sorry for the post issues. Wasn't really sure what to title this. 

I thought the 200% bG size was weird too, but when I try to make it 100%, the gradients end up acting weird or don't work at all. 

Anyone have a better approach to accomplish this progress-style animation?

Comment: I can only reproduce this with 67% zoom in Firefox 111.0a1, so it looks like this is a rounding issue. The “obvious” approach would be to nudge the background position a bit further to the left beyond the left edge, and further to the right beyond the right edge, however, your background also repeats. You could try making the background larger than the element itself, so one repetition covers more than the width of the element, or try to eliminate the repetition somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is on the right track, but I'd eliminate the odd `100vw` width on the connectors and instead make them flex. I'd then remove the 200% background size multiplier. By setting the gradient points to 100% the problem is gone. I really don't know if this covers your use case, though.

I converted from background gradient to a pseudo-element solution for the color transition. I think it's simpler. You'd probably have to use CSS animations (as opposed to simple transitions) to make it work otherwise. Of course, you could apply the same principle to the stage items as well, implementing a delay to crate a consistent animation across the item and the line.

Note that duplicated ID values are invalid in HTML. They *must* be unique. I've refactored to use data attributes instead and an event listener instead of inline JavaScript.

```js
const stageEls = document.querySelectorAll('.stage-flow-item')
const lineEls = document.querySelectorAll('.stage-flow-line')
let currentStage = 1

stageEls.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    performAction(el.dataset.stage)
  })
})

function performAction(selectedStage) {
  currentStage = selectedStage

  for (let el of stageEls) {
    if (el.dataset.stage > currentStage) {
      el.classList.remove('completed')
      el.classList.add('active')
    } else {
      el.classList.remove('active')
      el.classList.add('completed')
    }
  }

  for (let el of lineEls) {
    if (el.dataset.stage > currentStage) {
      el.classList.remove('lineCompleted')
      el.classList.add('lineActive')
    } else {
      el.classList.remove('lineActive')
      el.classList.add('lineCompleted')
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.stage-flow-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.stage-flow-item {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  min-width: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.stage-flow-item.active {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.stage-flow-item.completed {
  background-color: #6ab04c;
}

.stage-flow-line {
  flex: 1;
  height: 6px;
  background: #ddd;
  position: relative;
}

.stage-flow-line::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #6ab04c;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.stage-flow-line.lineCompleted::after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="stage-flow-container">
  <div data-stage=1 class="stage-flow-item">1</div>
  <div data-stage=1 class="stage-flow-line"></div>
  <div data-stage=2 class="stage-flow-item">2</div>
  <div data-stage=2 class="stage-flow-line"></div>
  <div data-stage=3 class="stage-flow-item">3</div>
</div>
```